Flutter SliverGroupedListView - Add Padding after each group
I have a list of events that take place grouped by date.
Id like to add a gap after each group by date.
If i add padding to top of each group header it brings the top one down also so need another solution. Is there any way to add a gap at the end of each group?
I seen something similar here but for a listview.builder
padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: index == connectors.length - 1 ? 0 : 24),


